# How to delete and rename columns for multiple files

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have multiple csv files. Some of them have 5 columns like this:

```
 Date         Open        High        Low        Close
2006/01/03  4762.2002   4782.7002   4751.1001   4776.0
2006/01/04  4786.7998   4823.3999   4776.0000   4820.3
2006/01/05  4820.1001   4831.0000   4807.2998   4813.7
2006/01/06  4813.6001   4813.7002   4784.7998   4791.1
2006/01/09  4803.5000   4834.7998   4791.1001   4831.5
```

Some of them have only 2 columns like this:

```
   Date      Close
01/04/2006  1245.739990
01/05/2006  1246.332593
01/06/2006  1247.555685
01/09/2006  1249.867750
01/10/2006  1253.140732
```

I wish to merge these columns together in one csv, and rename the "Close" column for each specific file. Because there is only the "Close" for some files, the data was deleted during the process. How to merge, rename and retain the "Close" data for these files?

This is what I tried earlier:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

for key, value in feature_df_dict.items():

columns_to_delete = ["Open", "High", "Low"]
for column in columns_to_delete:
    if column in feature_df_dict[key].columns:
        del feature_df_dict[key][column]

col = list(feature_df_dict[key].columns)
print(key)
print(col)

key_name = key.replace("path", "")
key_name = key_name.replace(".csv","")
col = [key_name+"_"+x for x in col if x!= 'Date']

colx = ['Date']

for colv in col:
    colx.append(colv)

feature_df_dict[key].columns = colx
```

Comment: What do you mean *'rename the "Close" column for each specific file'*? Correct its name back to 'Close' , or rename it to something else (what?)

Comment: For example: I have 3 csv files with names "a", "b", "c". I want to rename the "close" as "a_close", "b_close" and "c_close" on a new merged csv.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to do it that way? See the difference between 'wide-form' and 'long-form': 'long-form' would use rows with 'Date','Stock' and 'Close'. Then you could transform that into a 'wide-form' table of 'Close' prices by Stock and Date

Comment: Anyway if you want to do it long-form, it's best to have 'Close' as a prefix, so 'Close_AAPL', 'Close_INTC'... instead of 'AAPL_Close' etc. The `melt, reshape` functions understand column-name prefixes.

Comment: That's just my personal preference. I am more concern about the column data actually.